# Alternative to GROUP BY to get distinct results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a custom DMS (Laravel 8 and MySQL 8.0.27) and have two tables - documents with a few basic bits of information (id, confidentiality, document type etc.) and versions which contains everything else (title, filetype, original filename, various classification codes etc.) with a one-to-many relationship (one document has one or more versions).
I'm working with datatables.net on the front end and need to get a table that has the info from the documents table, and *just* the latest version of that document. The way I've done it so far was like this:

```
SELECT d.id, d.confidentiality, v.id as version_id, 
    v.title, v.system_code, v.system_code,
    v.version, v.updated_at, v.created_at, v.filename_orig 
FROM documents d
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM versions ORDER BY versions.created_at DESC) v
ON d.id = v.document_id
GROUP BY d.id
```

This works fine in phpmyadmin but in my app I get the error that boils down to "**this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**" which forces MySQL to act the way most DBs have so far - requiring that everything I SELECT appears in GROUP BY. The problem is that if I do this I no longer get a table with distinct document.id fields - I get every version associated with that document instead of just the latest one.
From what I've seen disabling only_full_group_by in my config would work but it doesn't seem to be recommended. I'd appreciate any ideas for a neater solution to this problem...

Edit: I think P.Salmon had the right idea. Read through the link and this seems to be working for me:

```
WITH latest AS (
  SELECT v.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.document_id ORDER BY v.created_at DESC) AS rn
  FROM versions v
)
SELECT * FROM LATEST l 
JOIN documents d ON l.document_id = d.id
WHERE l.rn = 1
```

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Yes, that SQL statement is malformed. All column that not included in the `GROUP BY` clause should be aggregated (MIN, MAX, SUM, etc) in the SELECT list.

Comment: @jarlh - MySQL 8.0.27, updated original post.